# Rxjs subject triggers twice in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject

I have a subject search2Sub$ that is being emitted twice. I trigger it only one time in component1 after user stopped typing. Could youp please help figuring out what am I doing wrong?

```
appService
search2Sub$ = new Subject<boolean>()

component1
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.appService.search1Sub$.pipe (
        debounceTime(2000), 
    ).subscribe(value => {
        this.appService.search2Sub$.next(true)
    });
}

component2
this.appService.search2Sub$.subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(value)
})
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.appService.search2Sub$.unsubscribe()
}
```

Comment: Is it only emitted twice? Or is it emitted the number of times the user stops typing? Because it could be that you stop writing, it's emitted, then you write again and stop, and it's emitted, and you continue writing and stoping and it is emitted again.

Comment: @lili is search1Sub$ a behaviourSubject?

Comment: @NarenMurali it is a subject. do you think it can be an issue?

Comment: @lili could you share a stackblitz with the issue replicate?

Comment: @René it is emitted 2 times for every time user stopped typing

Comment: @NarenMurali unfortunately, I can't

Comment: @lili no problem, glad its resolved!

Answer (score 1):

The resolution was saving as subscription  and then unsubscribe from it

```
subscription = this.appService.search2Sub$.subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(value)
})

if (subscription) {
subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

rxjs take operator didn't do a trick.